# Postgres: Getting the "partition number" instead of row_number

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count

Figure a table with the following data, how to exclude 'alone' values?

```
id; data
(1, 'foo'),
(2, 'foo'),
(3, 'foo'),
(4, 'bar'),
(5, 'bar');
(6, 'jak');
```

I try with this:

```
select id, data, row_number() over (partition by data)
from t;

 -- RESULT
id  data    row_number
4   bar     1
5   bar     2
1   foo     1
2   foo     2
3   foo     3
6   jak     1

 -- EXPECTED (exclude partition with one row)
id  data    row_number
4   bar     1
5   bar     2
1   foo     1
2   foo     2
3   foo     3
```

`row_number()` gives an index to rows in each partition.

How to have the number of rows by partition? Some kind of `WHERE partition_count > 1`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5047615fd7774c1ade021b85bb156e08)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count` as a window function:

```
SELECT id, data
FROM (SELECT id, data,
             count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY data) AS c
      FROM t) AS q
WHERE c > 1;
```

Comment: So simple, thanks. 'c' is missing from the SELECT in your answer.